# How to take backup of artifacts in azure devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I need to take backup of artifacts after we run the release pipeline. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you not able to complete what you are looking for with publish artifact step in the release pipeline? You can publish them to the Azure Devops server or on a network path.

Answer (score 0):

Artifacts are associated with the run they were produced in and remain available after the run has completed.

As a backup, you could publish these artifacts to Azure DevOps Server directly.

Aside from being published, Build and Release artifacts will **be available as long as that Build or Release is retained** unless otherwise specified. For more information on retaining Build and Release artifacts, see the [Retention Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) documentation.

If this does not meet your needs, just as  *HitzSPB* pointed out in the comment, you could also choose publish artifacts to a file share/**network path**.

More details please have a look at our official doc: [Publish and download artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)